# Why do I get an error running Get-WindowsCapability in PowerShell ISE on Windows Server 2012 r2?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running the PowerShell ISE on a Windows Server 2012 r2 machine.
When I run the following:

```
Get-WindowsCapability
```

I get the following error:

> Get-WindowsCapability : The term 'Get-WindowsCapability' is not
> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of  the name, or if a path was included,
> verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-WindowsCapability
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-WindowsCapability:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

Am I missing a PowerShell package?
How do get this feature working?

Thanks, JohnB

Answer (score 1):

`Get-WindowsCapability` is a cmdlet from the `DISM` module.

DISM was deployed natively with Server 2012 R2, but depending on the version of PowerShell or other configuration settings (like where your Windows partition is setup or image specific customizations), sometimes we find that we need to import the module before using it, like so:

```
Import-Module DISM 

#or, to see which commands are in the module
Import-Module DISM -Verbose
```

If this fails, double check that it wasn't removed somehow.  For instance, does it appear when you run the following?

```
Get-Module DISM -ListAvailable
```

If it doesn't appear, then it seems the module was removed and maybe the Windows component.  No worries, we can get it back with the module too by installing the Windows Automated Deployment Kit (ADK), [found here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39982).

*Update*: you may find the module under this path as well

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\`.
The module file to import would be under the `x86\DISM` folder or `x64\DISM`, and named `dism.psm1`

Comment: FoxDeploy - I've downloaded the ADK to the server; reran the Import-Module commands and Get-WindowsCapability still does not show up in the list of available cmdlets. Is there something else I am missing here?

Comment: Check the directory where you installed the ADK, you might just need to go to that folder path and import it directly.  The ISE itself also has some behavior that might be causing the newly installed items not to appear, so restart the ISE as well to check.

Comment: FoxDeploy - Restarted ISE, no change. I'm not sure what you mean by "import it directly?" ADK installed to c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1

Comment: Use Windows Explorer to search for a .psm1 file within the ADK directory and then import the full path of the file like this `Import-Module c:\PathTo\TheAdk\Folder\AndModule\adk.psm1`

Comment: FoxDeploy - searched and don't see adk.psm1. I only see dism.psm1. Is there another way to get adk.psm1?

Comment: My apologies, I updated my answer with the expected path for the DISM module.  If you don't find it there, install the ADK.

Comment: FoxDeploy - Searched hard drive. No adk.psm1. I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2, if that makes a difference.

Comment: it's  DISM.psm1, sorry.  If you can't find this, install the ADK tool from the link

Answer (score 1):

This command seems not to be available in Windows Server 2012. For a list of all available commands, see [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/?view=winserver2012r2-ps).