# running Get-WindowsCapability in PowerShell on Windows Server 2012 r2 is not recognized

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I got the problem like this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64336388/16485655).

> Get-WindowsCapability : The term 'Get-WindowsCapability' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1

Then try his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336645/16485655), doesn't work.

[Microsoft docs Server 2012 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/?view=winserver2012r2-ps) says there's no command of "Get-WindowsCapability".[Server 2012 R2 powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGUQy.png)

The command "Get-WindowsCapability" is shown in [Microsoft docs Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/?view=windowsserver2016-ps).[Server 2016 powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMMB1.png)

Is there a way for Server 2012 R2 to use command "Get-WindowsCapability"?

Comment: not without installing the dotnet framework that newer versions of PoSh require ... and then installing a newer version of PoSh. **_that may cause your software to fail to work ... upgrading the framework can make an app like exchange server fail to start or crash._**